# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed. (Ionic 3)

Tags: html, angular, api, ionic3, ngfor

I'm doing a project and I keep getting the error `Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed` I looked up the error and there are two ways to do it, change the incoming data(no possible) or "transform the object in my component". I need to do the latter, but I can't find any way how to as I'm only a student. Here's some of the relevant code:

**characters.ts**

```
     apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/people';

     getUsers() {
     return new Promise(resolve => {
     this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
     .subscribe(data => {
      resolve(data);
     }, err => {
     console.log(err);
    });
   });
```

**home.ts**

```
  users: any= [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: 
  CharactorsProvider) {
  this.getUsers();
 }


  getUsers() {
  this.restProvider.getUsers()
  .then(data => {
  this.users = data;
  console.log(this.users);
 });
 }
```

**home.html**

```
 <ion-list>
 <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
  <p>{{charactor.results}}</p>
 </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please any help with changing the code would be a huge help. I'm new to Ionic, only a few weeks in, and have a basic knowledge of it.

Edit: Code not in boxes.
Edit 2: API I'm using  https://swapi.co/api/people/

Comment: What does `console.log(this.users)` output?

Comment: what do you see when you put console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users));

Comment: @BenWest The Console.log outputs the array    
        {name: "Luke Skywalker", height: "172", mass: "77", hair_color: "blond", skin_color: "fair", …}

Comment: @Sajeetharan puts out the array 
        {"name":"Luke 
  
  
  Skywalker","height":"172","mass":"77","hair_color":"blond","skin_color":"fair","eye_color":"blue","birth_year":"19BBY","gender":"male","homeworld":"https://swapi.co/api/planets/1/", } etc, will post the api in post

Comment: You need an iterable (array) from your server responses. Basically you need to grab "results" array in the response.

Comment: Looks like you just have one user, not users.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko how would i go about doing that? I'm very new to ionic and angular and don't know enough to do that yet

Comment: @BenWest how would i go about changing that? I'm very new to ionic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well based on the JSON you posted above, it looks like you have a Object instead of array.

As the error stated above **`"Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed"`** you need array to iterate over using ngFor.

Either change your API to send the response as array, or push the object to an array.

Also you have an issue in ngFor variable

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
  <p>{{user.name}}</p> //access each user object from array
 </ion-item>
```

**`EDIT`**

When i looked in the response, actually you should access the results property from the response which is an array.

```
this.http.get('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        this.users = res.json().results; 
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.errorFromSubscribe = error;
});
```

[`HERE IS A WORKING STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-get-json-e1nieg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: if you are sure that api is returning only one object always, you can just do this.users.push(data);

Comment: @JackCaltagirone check the working stackblitz edit above