# Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed when I call get

Tags: angular, firebase

I have my `servers.service.ts` that does a `GET REQUEST` this:

```
  getServers(){
     return this.http.get('https://*******.firebaseio.com/data.json').map((response: Response)=>{const data=response.json();console.log(data);return data;});
}
```

And in my `app.component.ts` I do this:

```
onGet(){
    this.serverService.getServers().subscribe(
      (servers: any[])=> this.servers=servers,
      (error)=>console.log(error)
    );
  }
```

I use like db `firebase` and it throws this exception

> Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are
>   allowed

when I call  `onGet()`. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error trying to diff '\[object Object\]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed. (Ionic 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119750/error-trying-to-diff-object-object-only-arrays-and-iterables-are-allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ngFor only accept **array** format data. But your service returning non array object.that's the reason for why you are getting this error.

Try this below code

```
const data=response.json().results;
```

instead of

```
 const data=response.json()
```